# Need help with newspaper magazine design/layout

Tags: page-layout, critique

I am designing and doing the layout for our senior year newspaper. I want this to look as professional as I can get it. I feel like somthing is off with the design but I can not put my finger on what.

In advance Thank you!

Here is the newspaper:

[image]

[**More examples in this link.**](http://www.tvitre.org/r/pdf)

Comment: Hei og velkommen. What tools are you currently using; and what format will it end up as? Paper, online pdf, webpage, html?

Comment: How did it go? Boblet's answer is really good, did you get a chance to see it?

Answer (score 4):

I will try to point out some basic things. I do not know what software you are using to create this, and that wold be helpful to know. I am sure there are templates out there, readymade, but I am going to give some general pointers.

**[This blogpost will help you "dissect" newspaper layout.](http://kevin-wade.blogspot.no/2011/04/newspaper-research.html)**

The best thing you can do is to *look* at newspapers. Since I am familiar with the theme of your paper - russ - I will point out some general things, and suggest what I would have done in your shoes.

**Newspapers are based on a strict grid.**

**1. Your heading is all wrong.** It looks like you have a double nameplate (see image below). It is red and it has a horizontal line beneath it, this *removes* it from the content. Give the headline space, size and remove the horizontal line from underneath it. Here is an example of a simplified newspaper layout. Obviously, you can skip some of the elements:

[image]

**2. Newspapers usually have a *lead paragraph* (norwegian: ingress),** usually set in bold, italic or larger text. This is the "elevator pitch"; the sentence that will get people to read the article.

[image]

**3. Make a large heading large and in black**, and then create a byline *underneath*. A byline is the bit that says who wrote it. I would suggest you create a heading other than "fra redaktøren" and rather use a quote from the article. Then, in the byline, you write her name and add "redaktør" afterwards:

> **Heading that is a quote or summary**
>
> *Lead paragraph*
>
> Navn Navnesen, redaktør
>
> ---
>
> Article

**4. Use your columns.** Use the columns for the heading as well. Depending on the size of the paper, I would four columns is good: your heading can then span over two, three or four of them.

**5. Use a smaller and different font for the nameplate** This is **not** the most important information you have. Make it grey. And I would *move the kontonummer to the footer*. It is, in my view, pretty tasteless to have it in the header.

**6. Crop your images.** You want the reader "close" to the people; crop to headshots.

[image]

Your image of redaksjonen have a massive amount of pointless wall above the people (looks like they are falling out of the image, of off the page), the image of russestyret have a pointless amount of space below. Yes I know the image is supposed to show how cool these people are, but you do not need it. You want readers to see the *faces*. Centred text underneath those images is pointless, and the vertical line as well. You can tighten those elements *a lot. Very* crude mockup (ignore fonts):

[image]

**7. Place images so that the subjects are "looking" at your heading or the text.** It seems a little uninterested that they look away from the page.

**8. Make a footer.** Place the kontonummer below the horizontal line at the bottom.

**9. Use Boxes.** Put the content that is either not relevant to the article, or extra information, in a box with a *softly coloured background*. Pink, in this case, would make sense. Light grey is the classic. Quotes, practical information, titbits of other information you think useful.

**10. You *could* set the article text in justified flush right and left.** That means that both the right and left side of the text is *straight*. Personally, I am not a fan, but it certainly highlights the newspaper-look. Example:

[image]

**11. Let the article go across two pages.** You can also split two pages across. It gives a little more "life" to the two-page spread. As long as you stay with the four-column grid (that in this case will turn into an eight-column grid).

**Summary:**

Newspapers are **tight**. You should make the pages dense, without killing legibility. Use graphics if you have them to break up the pages a little. Your readers are young, so you can easily use pretty small font-sizes :D

Answer (score -2):

If you want a professional design then i would suggest you to buy a  template and then work on it.
Try Googling for Templates.

I personally use: http://graphicriver.net

All the best :)

Comment: This is a little short on explanation. Could you edit your post to include what applications you use what template for, and to include some examples? We try not to have link-only answers because of link rot.